# Need help in Xcode with "ViewController"

Tags: iphone, xcode, viewcontroller

I'm new to Xcode programming and I've been watching a couple videos here and there but one thing I never find on mine which the videos have. They have a file called "ViewController" (.h/.m). I don't have that, instead I have AppDelegate, RootView, DataView, and ModelController (all are .h/.m)

Comment: Please post some screenshots and excerpts from the tutorials illustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose the Single View Application template that contains ViewController. Or press command+N to create a new Cocoa Touch Class and make it subclass of UIViewController.

Comment: Oh thank you so much! I was using Page-Based Application before, I will see if I can do the same thing in Single View and let you know.